# Assign number based on date and unique identifier

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe that look like this:

| Date | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1/21/22 | 001 |
| 1/22/22 | 001 |
| 1/23/22 | 001 |
| 1/21/22 | 002 |
| 1/22/22 | 002 |
| 1/23/22 | 002 |

The entire dataframe is grouped by tag number and then sorted by date oldest to newest. I want to create a new column that assigns 1 for first capture 2 for second capture etc. and should look like this.

| Date | Tag | CaptureOrder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/21/22 | 001 | 1 |
| 1/22/22 | 001 | 2 |
| 1/23/22 | 001 | 3 |
| 1/21/22 | 002 | 1 |
| 1/22/22 | 002 | 2 |
| 1/23/22 | 002 | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `consecutive_id` function from the package `dplyr` version >= 1.1.0 while have the group on the `Tag` column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(CaptureOrder = consecutive_id(Date), .by = Tag)

     Date Tag CaptureOrder
1 1/21/22   1            1
2 1/22/22   1            2
3 1/23/22   1            3
4 1/21/22   2            1
5 1/22/22   2            2
6 1/23/22   2            3
```

Answer (score 2):

**base R** with `seq_along` by group:

```r
transform(df, CaptureOrder = ave(Tag, Tag, FUN = seq_along))

     Date Tag CaptureOrder
1 1/21/22   1            1
2 1/22/22   1            2
3 1/23/22   1            3
4 1/21/22   2            1
5 1/22/22   2            2
6 1/23/22   2            3
```

**data.table**, with `rowid`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, CaptureOrder := rowid(Tag)]
```

**dplyr**, with `row_number`:

```r
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, CaptureOrder = row_number(), .by = Tag)
```